# Accordion is not working in field group module

Tags: 8, entities, navigation

I have configured the [Field group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module for Drupal 8 to manage the display of my node into accordion.  I added an accordion wrapper, and assigned an accordion item into it. Lastly, added the fields into the accordion-item. 
But it does not seem to work as expected. Please suggest what I might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have installed and enabled https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_ui_accordion